# Delete files in a directory older than the current month in shell

Tags: shell

I want to know how to delete the files in a directory those are older than the current month?

I have tried for this-

Comment: Click the [edit] button to add the code you tried, and then we can help.

Comment: You cannot do that because Linux systems generally do not store a timestamp for the creation date, as can be read [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91197/how-to-find-creation-date-of-file). You could use the modification date though as *LittleQ* pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that 30 days per month,  use `find -mtime +30`

> -mtime n
>             File's  data was last modified n*24 hours ago.  See the comments
>             for -atime to understand how rounding affects the interpretation
>             of file modification times.